# Redis sunionstore returning Protocol error: invalid multibulk length

Tags: redis

I'm trying to run a sunionstore command, but somehow it crashes out with a `Protocol error: invalid multibulk length`.. the call is made with around 1.1M keys, which is a lot-ish, but shouldn't be for Redis, right?

I tried incrementally decreasing the number of keys and it started working again at around 1.05M. Also checked with first/last half only and both options work, so it's not an invalid key somewhere or anything.

Any ideas? Let me know if I can do something else to help debug.

PS. FWIW the call is being made from a node.js app, but I don't suppose that can be relevant can it.

PPS. Just tried running the same call with redis-py and the same thing happens (instead now it's `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 104 while writing to socket. Connection reset by peer.`)

The execution time of both successful and failed calls is very small, <1s, so that's unlikely to be the issue.

The issue happens regardless if the sets actually unify anything or not, i.e. fails even with some fake keys where the union is empty.

Comment: It could be a problem with your Node.js client library - try executing the same directly (i.e. with redis-cli or telnet) to rule that out.

Comment: see my comments, tried out with Python's redis-py, not sure how to run from redis-cli and input 1M keys

Comment: My bad for not reading thoroughly - I misunderstood and thought you had 1M values, not keys. In any case, doing a union (or any other variable arity command for that matter) on so many keys appears to be unsupported (the source code suggests a limit of 1024^2, but I may be wrong) - probably because no one thought anyone would want to do that in the first place. Put differently, even if it was supported  it's probably wrong practice. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Could you point me to that place in the source code please? 1024^2 does sound like what I'm hitting though. Trying to.. let's say collect all tweets about a set of links, where tweet ids are stored in per-link redis sets. That's fine, I'll think about a more scalable way of doing this :)

Comment: https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/bb7fea0d5ca7b3a53532338e8654e409014c1194/src/networking.c#L985

Comment: nice, thanks! Ill just need to structure the app differently then - you can add your comment as an "answer" I suppose.